# Rails 4 - Statesman - no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, states

I have a model called organisation request. I have put statesman files on this model.

I have a couple of other models which I have also added statesman to and those work fine.

When I try to use this state machine, I get errors which say:

```
o = OrganisationRequest.last
  OrganisationRequest Load (5.6ms)  SELECT  "organisation_requests".* FROM "organisation_requests"  ORDER BY "organisation_requests"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => #<OrganisationRequest id: 1, profile_id: 40, organisation_id: 1, created_at: "2016-07-30 21:38:25", updated_at: "2016-07-30 21:38:25"> 
2.3.0p0 :137 > o.current_state
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_state' for #<OrganisationRequest:0x007f920bb21110>
```

Can anyone see why?

```
 class OrganisationRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
        include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries




  # --------------- associations
  belongs_to :profile
    belongs_to :organisation
    has_many :organisation_request_transitions, autosave: false


  # --------------- scopes


  # --------------- validations


  # --------------- class methods

  def state_machine
    @state_machine ||= OrganisationRequestStateMachine.new(self, transition_class: OrganisationRequestTransition)
  end

   delegate :can_transition_to?, :transition_to!, :transition_to, :current_state,
           to: :state_machine




  # --------------- callbacks

  OrganisationRequest.after_transition(from: :requested, to: :approved) do |organisation_request, profile|
    profile.organisation_id.update_attributes!(organisation_id: matching_organisation.id)
      # add a mailer to send to the  user that is added to the org
  end

    OrganisationRequest.after_transition(from: :approved, to: :removed) do |organisation_request, profile|
    profile.organisation_id.update_attributes!(organisation_id: nil)
    end


  # --------------- instance methods

  # --------------- private methods

  private

    def self.transition_class
      OrganisationRequestTransition
    end

    def self.initial_state
      :requested
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

There were two errors in my setup:

The first was that I incorrectly named the class name as a variable in the has many association - it should be:

```
has_many :transitions, class_name: 'OrganisationRequestTransition', autosave: false
```

The second was that I had the after_transition callbacks in the organisation request model - they should be in the organisation request state machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't pass `association_name` into the function. Give it a try (not tested):

```
def state_machine
  @state_machine ||= OrderStateMachine.new(self, transition_class: OrderTransition, association_name: :organisation_request_transitions)
end
```

Comment: @Maverick_Tan - thanks for the suggestion. I tried it (even though I don't use that in my other state machine models). It didn't work - I still get an error that says: NoMethodError: undefined method `current_state' for #<OrganisationRequest:0x007f8ecc889250>

Comment: I also tried: association_name: :transitions - but i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think as per the [stateman gem](https://github.com/gocardless/statesman) it should be

```
<object>.state_machine.current_state
```

Eg

```
o = OrganisationRequest.last
o.state_machine.current_state
```

not

`o.current_state`

HTH

Comment: Thanks @sameera207 - the problem is because I setup the association wrong. Thanks so much for trying to help. For others, I added an answer above.